# linq .sum request exception

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to count the value of a row for each results.

Here is my request :

```
var resultat = _context.ODVCompteurs.Where(
                    odv => odv.SiteId == siteId && odv.DateODV >= firstDayOfMonth && odv.DateODV < lastDayOfMonth).Sum(x => x.NbrEntree);
return resultat;
```

everything works fine, except when the 'where' clause doesn't return any results. I expect to get '0' for result and I catch this exception :

> Null can not be assigned to a member System.Int32 type because it is a
>   non-nullable value type.

I could easily do a 'if' statement with a '.Count != 0' but I dont want to do two requests, I want to keep all the operation in one request.

Comment: Can you post the ddl for `ODVCompteurs`

Comment: "Not getting any results" is not the same as "catching an exception". So which of the two is the case with your `.Where`?

Comment: Looks like you *might* have a `NULL` value in your DB's equivalent of the `SiteId` or `DateODV` properties, and you didn't define these properties as nullable; or you did, but `firstDayOfMonth` or `lastDayOfMonth` aren't nullable and the compiler tries to coerce `SiteId` / `DateODV` into non-nullable ints in order to compare.

Comment: After checking in the database, It looks like when the 'where' clause doesn't return any row, the members of the .Sum (who is Int32 type) is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    var resultat =
            _context.ODVCompteurs.Where(
                odv => odv.SiteId == siteId && odv.DateODV >= firstDayOfMonth && odv.DateODV < lastDayOfMonth)
                .ToArray();

        return resultat.Length != 0 ? resultat.Sum(x=>x.NbrEntree) : 0;
```

Comment: I already did this but the .any and .sum will get two differents requests.

Comment: This would force two requests to be run - and the OP say he doesn't want that.

Comment: @Enigmativity I just add `.ToList();` to the query, so it will only send one query request to sql

Comment: @Tim.Tang - It's better to call `.ToArray()` rather than `.ToList()` as it is more memory efficient. However, in this case I don't know if it still solves the problem. Calling `.Sum()` on an empty sequence of nullable values results in zero.

Comment: I solved my problem using a ToArray. after that, I check the number of iteration in this array, and if it's differents than 0, I return the sum of it. It only makes one request because the end of the traitment is on the array and there is no interraction with database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in your entity that your dbset "ODVCompteurs" is composed of,  you have a nonnullable Int32 which maps to a Nullable column in your database. And when you fetch records from DB, if any of the rows contain null value for that nonnullable column you get the mentioned exception as EF is trying to bind the null value to our actual property, which does not accept null value. The easiest and most commonly (probably the only) way is to turn `Int32` to `Nullable<Int32>` or simply `int?` and your sorrows will be gone

To better demonstrate the problem, let's say we have a table in our database called Employee:

```
   CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE 
(
  ID NUMBER(5, 0) NOT NULL 
, NAME VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL 
, AGE NUMBER(3, 0) 
);
```

And here's the entity that maps to that table:

```
public class Employee{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Age {get;set;} //This is the source of a potential exception
}
```

You won't get any exception if all the rows you fetch contain a value different from null in the `AGE` column. But if any of the records have null for `AGE` then you get that exception. So just change that problematic line to this:

```
public int? Age {get;set;}
```

Comment: You're right, the member who is a Int32 is the member used bu the .Sum and I'm not allowed to modify the value of the member

Answer (score -1):

Try using .DefaultIfEmpty(0). What this will do is return a single 0 row if the collection is empty before the .Sum() gets applied.

```
var resultat = _context.ODVCompteurs.Where(
                    odv => odv.SiteId == siteId && odv.DateODV >= firstDayOfMonth && odv.DateODV < lastDayOfMonth)
               .Select(x => x.NbrEntree)
               .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
               .Sum();
return resultat;
```

Comment: I can't add the '0' value in the 'DefaultIfEmpty' method, and when I try I got the same exception

Comment: Sorry I just edited my answer with correct code. You need to first select the column you want before applying .DefaultIfEmpty(0). Afterwards, you can apply .Sum(), now without any parameters as you will already have the column selected.

Comment: I correct my sentence and get this exception : `Overload unsupported used for query operator 'DefaultIfEmpty'`